# How to get CSS Selector from DOMElement PHP Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, xpath, css-selectors

In Chrome I can inspect an Element -> right click -> copy -> copy Xpath (or selector).

Now, using PHP Symfony I find an Element like this, lets assume it returns 1 DOMElement node:

```
$node = $crawler->filterXPath("//*[text()='Super dee question']");
```

Now, how can I receive the CSS selector as if this $node were a node on Google Chrome, and I did the steps above: right click and inspect $node on chrome page -> copy -> copy Xpath. Obviously I'm not looking for an Xpath that contains 'Super Dee', but something more like

```
//*[@id="product_addtocart_form"]/div[2]/h1
```

EDIT: It appears that I can do DOMNode::getNodePath ( void ), however when using Chrome it usually can identify the nearest @id and use that, which is much more accurate than DOMNode::getNodePath ( void ) which looks something like:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[2]/h1
```

Comment: Why don't you use Javascript?

Comment: That's an option too. It seems I can do DOMNode::getNodePath() but the Chrome results are much cleaner, using things like @id to identify elements instead of just traversal down from HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM Crawler, at least when testing, allows such statements as:
`$housingText = trim($crawler->filter("#household_housing option:selected")->text());`, where `household_housing` is a unique `id` of a drop-down, and returns the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS attributes selector like this

```
$housingText = trim($crawler->filter('[id="household_housing"] option:selected')->text());
```

For more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors